# Knockout.js binding template to display popup

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to display multiple popups (all of them together) with `knockout.js`.

I have used the following fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xh2jrpm/1/)

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in displaying .

```
options.close = function() {
  allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible(false);
};
```

The above code showing dialogVisible to be undefined everytime.
Any clues ?

Comment: I don't see that you ever create it.

Comment: What do mean by ever create it . Using the dialog won't create it ?

Comment: I missed this line: `      $(element).dialog(options);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectedVisible` is an observable which is supposed to contain a Product, right? You're trying to bind its `isOpen` member as if it belongs to `selectedVisible` rather than to its contents. You need to say `selectedVisible()` to get at its contents. However, its contents start out undefined, which is going to be a problem when you try to take their `isOpen` member.